# javascript not well-formed

Tags: javascript, html

I have an hmtl file which includes another javascript as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
<div>
something
</div>
```

This html file is loaded via de .load()
and it loads it in a div from the main page

This tells me that the first line is not well-formed

```
$(".flip").live("click", function() {

         $(this).find("div.panel").slideToggle("slow")
     });
     $(".flip").live("mouseover", function() {
         $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
     });
```

If i remove this, it will tell me the next element is not well-formed and so on. If I include this javascript in a page which is not called via .load, it doesn't say any error. Is this because i'm calling this java script inside a div? and not in the head?

Comment: Can you give it online? Mabe on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try to write the javascript code inde this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Here insert your javascript code
});
```

Comment: if i do that it says the same that $(document).ready not well formed, I originally had it like that, it's pretty strange, It says that error only when I use the .load()